# How to place absolute positioned element outside of relative parent CSS

Tags: html, css, position

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.parent {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    
}

.child {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

</style>
```

I need green box to go outside of red box, it needs to be stuck on left of screen always. Is it possible with css?
without using .parent {position: unset;} or something like that.

[image]

Comment: Try `left: -200px;`

Comment: @Simp4Code not bad, but I need green box to stuck always left of screen dynamically on every device.

Comment: right:100% ? instead of left:0

Comment: @SatishThakur if you want it always to be stuck to left of the screen then use `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to position the child element based on the viewport then use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;` -- hover anywhere in the snippet below to see the parent move while the child stays in the same place on the left of the screen

```css
body { height: 100vh; margin: 0; display: grid; place-items: center; }



.parent {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  transition: all 500ms 0ms ease-in-out;
}
.child {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 25vw;
  background: green;
  
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

body:hover .parent {
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Based on a comment from OP this answer is no longer appropriate but it still valid based on how the question is worded*

You can do it with `position: absolute;` by putting in a negative value, or a value greater the the size of the parent. Otherwise it can be done with `transform: translate( [X]px, [Y]px );` and it works much like position absolute but is better for performance!

```css
body { margin: 0 }




.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
}
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.75;
  
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent1 {
  position: relative;
}

.parent1 .child {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: -50px;
}

.parent2 {}

.parent2 .child {
    transform: translate(-50px, -50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent parent1">
    <div class="child">
      Position
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent2">
    <div class="child">
      Transform
    </div>
</div>
```